ReactNative enviroment setup failed

I get this error While setting up the enviroment of Reactnative.
I want help who know react native very well.
The error i have attched see and explane me what is the problem.
This error comes when i start my recatnative application.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

You should add the missing dependencies, e.g. install the proper Java JDK and Android SDK that appear to be missing.

seems like you just need to install JDK with any version between 17 and 20 and also install android sdk version 34.0.0

i have already installed but it not working

@Bholasankananda have you also added both of these to your environement variables?
